# "failed to fill whole buffer" error message when trying to deserialise an object in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, accumulator

I am trying to deserialise an object of type [`MembershipWitness`](https://docs.rs/vb_accumulator/latest/vb_accumulator/witness/struct.MembershipWitness.html) from a `[u8]` submitted by the user via rest api. The input from the user is a string which contains the bytes separated by a comma, so I had to parse this string an convert it to `[u8]`.

```
let mut witness_bytes: [u8; 32] = [0; 32];
let mut decoded_witness_elements = decoded_witness.split(",");
let mut k=0;
for s in decoded_witness_elements {
    witness_bytes[k] = s.parse::<u8>().unwrap();
    k=k+1;
}

let mut witness: &[u8] = &witness_bytes;
let witness_membership = <MembershipWitness<G1Affine>>::deserialize(witness).unwrap();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IoError(Error { kind: UnexpectedEof, message: "failed to fill whole buffer" })',
```

This is related to the last line of of the above code.

Please note that I am using the crate: https://crates.io/crates/vb_accumulator.

Here are some screenshots that hopefully helps in understanding the issue:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `MembershipWitness<G1Affine>`?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. You can see the details of MembershipWitness from the vb_accumulator documentation: https://docs.rs/vb_accumulator/0.7.0/vb_accumulator/witness/struct.MembershipWitness.html 

Please let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Thank you @user4815162342. I've just added some screenshots that hopefully give you more insight about the issue. Please let me know.

Comment: This error message normally means that there is an issue (such as corruption) in transport between serialization and deserialization. I'd first try to serlialize the data and immediately deserialize it, just to check if that works. Then I'd try logging the serialized data, and logging the deserialized data, to see if they match. Also, please don't post screenshots of textual data, just include the relevant data in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much @user4815162342 for the advice. I've manged to identify the issue based on your recommendation.